# How can I fix MySQL query to solve "Unknown column...in On clause" error?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help fix this query? I tried just about everything I could think of with no luck.

I have the below MySQL query and it spits out the below error

**ERROR:**
Unknown column 'SR.sales_rec_id' in 'on clause'

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT 
  SYSKEY.cri_sr_id,
  SR.sales_rec_id,
  SYSKEY.adnum,
  charge,
  SYSKEY.cancelsale,
  paymentdue,
  merchant,
  paymentnum,
  authorization as authcode,
  CONCAT(lastname,', ',firstname,' ',middleinitial) as customer, 
  CONCAT(replname,', ',repfname) as repname,    
FROM CRI_SR_KEYS as SYSKEY
  INNER JOIN SALES_PENDING as SPEND on SPEND.sales_rec_id=SR.sales_rec_id
  INNER JOIN SALES_RECORD as SR on SR.cri_sr_id=SYSKEY.cri_sr_id 
  LEFT JOIN CLIENT_INFO as CI on CI.client_id = SYSKEY.clientid 
  LEFT JOIN SALES_REPS as REP on SR.rep_id=REP.repid    
WHERE SPEND.authorization NOT LIKE '000000' AND paymentdue LIKE CURDATE() 
ORDER BY adnum ASC LIMIT 0,5000
```

Comment: Note there's an errant comma after `repname` before the `FROM` clause...

Comment: Join table **SALES_RECORD as SR** before **SALES_PENDING as SPEND**

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange the order of your joins so that `SR` is aliased before you try to use it:

```
SELECT 
  SYSKEY.cri_sr_id,SR.sales_rec_id,
  SYSKEY.adnum,charge,
  SYSKEY.cancelsale,paymentdue,merchant,paymentnum,authorization as authcode,
  CONCAT(lastname,', ',firstname,' ',middleinitial) as customer, 
  CONCAT(replname,', ',repfname) as repname    
FROM CRI_SR_KEYS as SYSKEY
  INNER JOIN SALES_RECORD as SR on SR.cri_sr_id=SYSKEY.cri_sr_id 
  INNER JOIN SALES_PENDING as SPEND on SPEND.sales_rec_id=SR.sales_rec_id
  LEFT JOIN CLIENT_INFO as CI on CI.client_id = SYSKEY.clientid 
  LEFT JOIN SALES_REPS as REP on SR.rep_id=REP.repid    
WHERE SPEND.authorization NOT LIKE '000000' AND paymentdue LIKE CURDATE() 
ORDER BY adnum ASC LIMIT 0,5000
```

There's also a stray comma after `repname` in the SELECT clause but that could just be a typo.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, the extra comma was a typo. The issue was fiexed just by re-arranging the join.

Answer (score 1):

If the column `SALES_RECORD.sales_rec_id` does actually exist, reorder your `JOIN` statements:

```
FROM CRI_SR_KEYS as SYSKEY
  /* Move this above SALES_PENDING to SR */
  INNER JOIN SALES_RECORD as SR on SR.cri_sr_id=SYSKEY.cri_sr_id 
  INNER JOIN SALES_PENDING as SPEND on SPEND.sales_rec_id=SR.sales_rec_id
  LEFT JOIN CLIENT_INFO as CI on CI.client_id = SYSKEY.clientid 
  LEFT JOIN SALES_REPS as REP on SR.rep_id=REP.repid
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe it was that simple.  Worked perfectly.